# Maven + Jersey RESTful API : Internal Server Error from POSTMAN on GET request

Tags: java, json, maven

I am sending a GET request to my `StoryBoardResource`, class responsible for generating `JSON` format data, using POSTMAN app. The associated method consumes nothing but produces `Application/JSON` data: `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

I am recieving **500 internal server error** on POSTMAN though there is nothing showing up on my IDE's console as am logging some statements too for debugging purpose.

If there had been some **jar** file issue it must have thrown an error for `no MesageBodyWriter found` ...right? I have updated **pom.xml** to include `JSON` dependency and the jar is also there.

Here is my `StoryBoardResource` class to which the request is delegated:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.harsh.webapp.storyBoard.model.StoryBoardModel;
import org.harsh.webapp.storyBoard.service.StoryBoardService;

@Path("/authenticateUser")
public class StoryBoardResource {

private StoryBoardService sts = new StoryBoardService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public StoryBoardModel authUser(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password){
    return sts.authUser(username, password);
}
}
```

which calls `authUser` method on my service class `StoryBoardService` :

```
public StoryBoardModel authUser(String username, String password){
    System.out.println("In here");
    if(username.equals(map.get(username).getUsername()) && password.equals(map.get(username).getPassword())){
        System.out.println("true");
        return map.get(username);
    }
    return map.get(username);
}
```

Could this be bcoz of some **jar or Jersey version conflict**? 
Here is my `pom.xml`

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.harsh.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>storyBoard</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>storyBoard</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>storyBoard</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And here is a snapshot of **Maven Dependencies**

[image: Maven Dependency jars]

Sorry for such a long post but I thought I should explain things clearly.
Please help on finding what could I be doing wrong here?

And `web.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.harsh.webapp.storyBoard</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: 500 means something failed on the server. Where is the stack trace from the server?  How about error logs?

Comment: Check the response tab in POSTMAN.. If there is an error before controller method is invoked, it'll definitely present in POSTMAN response..

Comment: There is nothing showing up on my IDE's console. So cannot say what the error is? and I don't know where will the logs be stored.I am using Eclipse

Comment: @TheCoder : POSTMAN's response tab shows an html with a message : `Internal Server Error` and description as: `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`

Comment: @Harshavardhan: Did u do the web.xml mapping?

Comment: @Lathy: Yes I did. Check the post again I have included my web.xml too

Comment: Do you see the Systeem.out.printlns you are using in the code. Can you try having one directly inside the  authUser method. Also check if the correct username and password are getting input to the method ?FInally look at the "raw" return result on POSTMAN. Or maybe use Fiddler .

Comment: which URL r u using.. Can you change your web.xml url mapping to just  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: I have tried that too. But here is another prob. with what I did. I updated my `pom.xml` just now to include `artifactId` which says `use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility` and now I am having this error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` I did UnDo that in my pom.xml but now this error stays! :(
Please help..will be much appreciated...thnx

Comment: I hope you use something like this..http://localhost:<portNumber>/<your application Name>/authenticateUser/

Comment: @Lathy :This is my URL I am sending GET request with POSTMAN: `http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/webapi/authenticateUser?username=someusername&password=somepassword`

Comment: Just go back to your last change and do a clean build of the project in eclipse and restart server .

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki: Pl change the url mapping as i mentioned in my previous comment. use below url, http://localhost:7070/<your projectName>/authenticateUser?username=someusername&‌​password=somepassword

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: I cleaned my project and restarted the server. But still the same error!

Comment: can you check if one of the jars got deleted from the system. Go to the project in file explorer and check all the jars are there. Also check if the jars are present under the server libraries folder.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki Are you sure you added aplication/json header in postman while requesting. Because your code seems to be right.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: Hey thnx a lot now the project is running. But the old `Internal Server Error` is still there. But thnx for your help! :)

Comment: @DhruvPal: My GET method consumes no data so why should I send any header? please explain if I am missing the point!

Comment: So when you send the request to the server do you see the system.out.printlns ?  Also check the raw out put of POSTMAN .

Comment: @Lathy: I tried what you suggested but it seems to be same to what I did. Still not working! Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: Yes whatever am printing to the console with `System.out..` is printing successfully. Also the RAW output points to the same error nothing new. This prob. appears to be a lot in depth I am thinking now~ :(

Comment: So the raw output does not give you any exception stack trace etc ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: No no stack trace nothing. Just that `some internal server error prevented from fulfilling`

Comment: Ok . How about changing the @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) to the @produces(plain text)annotation and checking if i see the error in case i return a plain text . At least we will be sure if its a setup issue or a code issue.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: Ok did that. Now the console says
`MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain, type=class org.harsh.webapp.storyBoard.model.StoryBoardModel, genericType=class org.harsh.webapp.storyBoard.model.StoryBoardModel.
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106883/discussion-between-harshvardhan-solanki-and-som-bhattacharyya).

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki oh yeah I saw that

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya Oh yes..It appeared so that I missed to add a `No-Argument ` constructor in the model class I created. It was so mentioned in a tutorial I was following but I don't know the reason why it is so? You know why we need to add a `No-Arg` constructor??

Comment: hmm that sounds like Hibernate to me. Many frameworks mandate that as they do most of their work through reflection and a no arg constructor.In short they use `Class<T>.newInstance()` kind of syntax for their code generation purposes. Its the same reason here as well.

Comment: PostMan needs to be informed that the RESPONSE is also of JSON type. You can set that by adding the following in the Request Header. Key - "Accept" and Value "application/json". Worked for me after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out and it appeared so that I missed adding a `NO-Argument`constructor in a model class.

```
public someClass(){};
```

Always remember to add a `No-Arg` constructor whenever you create a model class for your `Maven-Jersey` application. 
And it worked!

However, I am not clear on why would a no-arg constructor make the application run or fail!!

If any body know the answer to this. Please share your knowledge!!

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer.